# How to separate the value from column and display into another column that is stored with special characters-postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, case

I have table name as `res_scheduledjobs`. In this table their is column as `sq_name_new1`. The values stored into `sq_name_new1` column as:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]+----------------------------------------------------------
sq_name_new1 | M&R(Mangesh Raghoji Raorane,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)
-[ RECORD 2 ]+----------------------------------------------------------
sq_name_new1 | andheri 3(Santosh Navnath Mule,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)
-[ RECORD 3 ]+----------------------------------------------------------
sq_name_new1 | andheri 4(Mahadev Pandurang Gurav,Ganesh Vasant Wagh)
-[ RECORD 4 ]+----------------------------------------------------------
sq_name_new1 | andheri 2(Pradeep Bhikaji Mohite,Amol Sopan Auti)
```

I want result as:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]+---------------------------------------------------------- 
sq_name_new1 | M&R(Mangesh Raghoji Raorane,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)
new_column    | Mangesh Raghoji Raorane
-[ RECORD 2 ]+---------------------------------------------------------- 
sq_name_new1 | M&R(Mangesh Raghoji Raorane,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)
new_column    | Ramesh Jagannath Kamble
```

means the values inside the column should gets separated. There should be no special characters as well as initials(like M&R) along with names.

Comment: Could you format your text and display the output as source code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  select *,unnest(string_to_array(substring(sq_name_new1,'\((.*)\)'),',')) new_column from mytable
```

Comment: hie,by using your query still it showing me output with : 
sq_name_new1 | ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado)
new_column      | E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam
i want it should dispay the result as :

sq_name_new1 | ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado)
new_column      |  Mangesh Govind Mogam

please help me to come out of this.

Comment: change pattern of substring : '\(([^()]*)\)$' instead of '\((.*)\)'